# Using 'geo.??' meta tags to geo-tag a blog post

Tags: html, meta-tags, geotagging

I am developing a blog post website, where each post will be about some location. Can I use geo meta tags to tag a post with that location? In this example, a post would be about New York.
Are those tags made to be used like this or just to tell a crawler that my website generally is from some region?

```
<meta name="geo.placename" content="New York" />
<meta name="geo.position" content="x;x" />
<meta name="geo.region" content="usa" />
<meta name="ICBM" content="x,x" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use these geo tags in HTML5 documents, the relevant definition comes from https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions, where it says:

> […] to which the page is related

As specifications, it lists:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daviel-html-geo-tag-08
- http://geotags.com/geo/geotags2.html

The expired draft (from 2007) [*Geographic registration of HTML documents*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daviel-html-geo-tag-08) clarifies in the [section *Applicability*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daviel-html-geo-tag-08#section-7):

> The geographic position given is associated with the resource described by the HTML document, not with the physical location of the document […], or the location of the company responsible for publishing or hosting the document.

The geotags.com page [*Geo Tag Elements*](http://geotags.com/geo/geotags2.html) clarifies in the section *Notes*:

> The tags describe the position of the resource described on the page, for instance a beach or restaurant, not the company hosting the page, the company managing the resource, or the server hosting the page

So following the interpretation from both specifications (**tl;dr**): If your page is about New York, using geo tags referencing New York is appropriate.